# swift 3 server response with strange dictionary format

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3, response

Will be grateful for help
I get server response with strange dictionary format

```
Data: {
    "featureHelpshift" = "true";
    "featureAppleTVSynchronisation" = "false";
    "featureDirectPlay" = "true";
    "googleLoginSwitchOn" = "true";
    "serverVersion" = "6.11.1";
    "facebookLoginSwitchOn" = "true";
    "allAvailableWorlds" = (
        {
            "name" = "\U0420\U043e\U0441\U0441\U0438\U044f 16 (\U043d\U043e\U0432\U044b\U0439)";
            "mapURL" = "https://backend2.lordsandknights.com/maps/LKWorldServer-RU-16";
            "worldStatus" = {
                "id" = "3";
                "description" = "online";
            };
            "country" = "RU";
            "language" = "ru";
            "id" = "190";
            "url" = "https://backend2.lordsandknights.com/XYRALITY/WebObjects/LKWorldServer-RU-16.woa";
        },...
```

first i try to serialize this response to JSON with swiftyJSON and json serializer

Than i get response as Data and parse it to String

```
func some () {
    Alamofire.request(serverRequest, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseData { response in

            if let data = response.result.value, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                //print("Data: \(utf8Text)") //- server response that shown above i print here
                print("Change->")
                let str = self.responseToJsonParsing(stringResponse: utf8Text)
                print("Data: \(str)")
            }

        }
}
```

i try to lead my data string response to JSON string format, create function for parsing:

```
func responseToJsonParsing(stringResponse: String) -> String {
        var parseResponse = stringResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ";\n\t\t}", with: "\n\t\t}", options: .literal)
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ";\n\t\t\t}", with: "\n\t\t\t}", options: .literal)
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ";\n\t}", with: "\n\t}", options: .literal)
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ";\n}", with: "\n}", options: .literal)
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ";", with: ",")
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: ":")
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "[")
        parseResponse = parseResponse.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "]")

        return parseResponse
    }
```

after parsing i still cant create JSON or Dictionary

Comment: That original response is not JSON. It looks like it was JSON that's already been parsed and is now displayed as a dictionary. Show us how you a retrieved and subsequently displayed that first "JSON".

Comment: server response that shown above i will get after i make  " let data = response.result.value, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) print(utf8Text) "

Comment: If that's really what the server is delivering, you should fix the server if you have access to it. I'm just hard pressed to figure out how the server produced that...